# VetorTest.java uses unchecked and unsafe operation With -Xlint error

Tags: java, vector

I am getting this error but don't know how to resolve it.I have already gone through the post but still confused.
I tried to run Xlint File.java but its not working.
While running this code, I am getting the msg like

**"VectorTest.java uses unchecked or unsafe operation**

**Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details"**

```
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class VectorTest
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {

       Vector v=new Vector(3,4);
       System.out.println("Initial size"+ v.size());
       System.out.println("Initial capacity"+ v.capacity());
       v.addElement(new Integer(1));
       v.addElement(new Float(2.5));
       v.addElement(new Double(3.45));
       v.addElement(new Integer(4));
       v.addElement(new Integer(5));
       System.out.println("Current Capacity"+ v.capacity());

       v.addElement(new Integer(6));
       v.addElement(new Integer(7));
       v.addElement(new Integer(8));
       v.addElement(new Integer(9));
       v.addElement(new Integer(10));
       v.addElement(new Integer(11));
       v.addElement(new Integer(12));
       System.out.println("Current Capacity"+ v.capacity());
       System.out.println("First element"+(Integer) v.firstElement());
       System.out.println("Last element"+(Integer)v.lastElement());
       Enumeration e;
       e= v.elements();
       while(e.hasMoreElements())
       {
          System.out.println("All elements"+ e.nextElement());
       }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Vector` class is generic; you should specify the type of objects it contains. In your case, it looks like you should declare it to contain either `Object` or `Number` (both of which are superclasses of everything you seem to be adding):

```
Vector<Number> v = new Vector<>(3,4); // or new Vector<Number>(3,4) if pre-Java 7
```

The warning should then go away.

As an aside, it is better to use the construct `Integer.valueOf(1)`, etc. instead of `new Integer(1)`. It allows re-use of `Integer` objects that may be cached, cutting down on memory use.

Comment: +1 for explanation, using Java 7 and the `valueOf` best practice

Comment: sorry but i am not able to grab the concept of Vector<number>=new Vector<>(3,4); What is the use of <number> here, can you please explain

Comment: @user2545197 - `Number` (not `number`) is the base class for `Integer`, `Float`, etc. The notation `<Number>` is how one specifies a type parameter when using a generic class. `Vector<Number>` tells the compiler that this particular `Vector` will only hold instances of `Number`. Generics provide a way of improving type safety at compile time, as well as greatly reducing the need to cast objects to specific types. See the [Java tutorial on generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) for more information about this.

Comment: Thanks, but pls may i know that if i place <Number> in Vector, in this way am i going to restrict my vector elements to be only a Number type of values..correct me if i am asking the wrong question..thanks in advance.

Comment: @user2545197 - If you want no restriction on what you place in a `Vector`, then you can always use `<Object>` as your type parameter. That places no restrictions, since anything that goes into a `Vector` must be an `Object` (the collection classes cannot contain primitive values). You sacrifice all type checking at compile time, but if that's what you need.... Not that a bare `Vector` and `Vector<Object>` are functionally (and semantically) identical; the difference is that in the second case you've explicitly told the compiler what you want, so it won't issue any warnings.

Comment: thats really grt..it solves all my problems..A Big Thanks to you

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the generics types.
You could declare your Vector as

```
Vector<Number> v = new Vector<Number>(3, 4);
```